# How to retrieved aspnetboilerplate core project localization information in server side

Tags: c#, localization, aspnetboilerplate

Work on aspnetboilerplate core project, my localization configuration, and use process as following.

**Application Languages in HRISLocalizationConfigurer.cs file**

```
localizationConfiguration.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("en", "English", "famfamfam-flags england"));            
localizationConfiguration.Languages.Add(new LanguageInfo("fr", "french", "famfamfam-flags fr", isDefault: true));
```

**Configure in Startup.cs file**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = true; }); 
}
```

On the server Side not get configured localization information always get the default en key value information. Server-side syntax is

```
 var localizeInfo = _localizationManager.GetSource(HRISConsts.LocalizationSourceName);

 var localizeResult = _localizationManager.GetString(HRISConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "HomePage");
```

In localizeResult always get en key"HomePage" value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve localized information bellow syntax used.

Need to inject two following services

```
private readonly ILocalizationManager _localizationManager;
private readonly ILocalizationConfiguration _configuration;
```

To retrieved localized information use above services

```
        var localizeResult = _localizationManager
            .GetString(HRISConsts.ConnectionStringName,
            "HomePage",
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(_configuration.Languages.FirstOrDefault(l => l.IsDefault).Name)
            );
```

Note: HRISConsts.ConnectionStringName is static string.